# Triggering page_load event via POST request

Tags: jquery, vb.net, post, devexpress, facebook-javascript-sdk

My question is simple: If I send a POST request to a aspx page, does the Page_Load event trigger? IF not, how can I properly handle a POST request on my page?

To get into more detail:
I have been working with Facebook API to make a simple research of user profile pages, given the name of the user.

I have a DevExpress EditForm that contains info regarding the contact, and a "Search with Facebook" Button that does this:

```
function facebookLogin() {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    FB.api('/search?type=user&q={' + edNomeAnagrafica.GetText() + ' ' + edCognomeAnagrafica.GetText() + '}', function (response) {
                        $.post("RicercaFBLoop.aspx", "Json=" + JSON.stringify(response.data) + "&paging=" + JSON.stringify(response.paging.next) + "&contatore=0");

                    });
                }
            }, { scope: 'email', return_scopes: true });
```

edNomeAnagrafica and edCognomeAnagrafica contain the name and surname of the contact.

RicercaFBLoop.aspx is a WebForm structured this way:

```
   <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="RicercaFBLoop.aspx.vb" Inherits="SportCardEvolution.RicercaFBLoop" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function StartLoop() {
            var c = txContatore.Text;
            if (c === 0) {
                txValoreSessione.Text = "Clear";
            }
            c++;
            txValoreSessione.Text = txJson.Text;
            if (txPaging.Text === null)
            {
                window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl("ElencoFB.aspx") %>';
            }
            $.get(txPaging.Text)
                .done(function (result) {
                        $.post("~/RicercaFBLoop.aspx", "Json=" + result.data + "&paging=" + result.paging.next + "&contatore=" + c);
                });



        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txJson" ClientInstanceName="txJson" runat="server" Visible="False"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txPaging" ClientInstanceName="txPaging" runat="server" Visible="false"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txContatore" ClientInstanceName="txContatore" runat="server" Visible="false"  ClientSideEvents-ValueChanged ="StartLoop"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
        <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="txValoreSessione" ClientInstanceName="txValoreSessione" runat="server" Visible="false" OnTextChanged="txSessionValue_TextChanged"></dx:ASPxTextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

while this is the codebehind (RicercaFBLoop.aspx.vb):

```
Public Class RicercaFBLoop
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    txJson.Text = Request.Form("Json")
    txPaging.Text = Request.Form("Paging")
    txContatore.Text = Request.Form("Contatore")

End Sub


Protected Sub txSessionValue_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txValoreSessione.TextChanged
    If (txValoreSessione.Text = "Clear") Then
        Session("ElencoFB") = ""
    Else
        Session("ElencoFB") += txValoreSessione.Text
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

My intent was to retreive the values sent by the POST request, trigger the StartLoop() javascript function that would put the values into another hidden field (and via the hidden field inside a session field), and send a POST to herself until there were more pages to scroll. Unfortunately, when I debug, I can properly see the POST request but nothing happening after that. I have not been able to debug RicercaFBLoop.aspx's JS code.

So i wonder if I have taken the right approach.

Comment: You are only making a POST request to the server that requests the _code_ - but that code does not get interpreted or executed anywhere. You would have to first of all take that code you got in response and insert it into the current document, resp. create a new window/tab and insert it into there, before there is even a remote chance of any of your JS code inside `RicercaFBLoop.aspx` getting executed by anyone ...

Comment: Ok, got it. If you put that in an answer, maybe with an example or something, I'll mark you as the right answer